# .htaccess rewrite rule not working without trailing slash?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the follow URLs:

```
www.website.com/index.php?section=index
www.website.com/index.php?section=freebies
www.website.com/index.php?section=deals
www.website.com/index.php?section=articles
```

and the following pagination url parameter for each:
page=1
for example

```
www.website.com/index.php?section=freebies&page=1
```

I am using the rewrite rules below to change the URL to:

```
www.website.com/freebies/1 etc
```

`www.website.com/freebies/1` and `www.website.com/freebies/` work correctly
but if I remove the trailing slash for example:

```
www.website.com/freebies
```

It is showing `www.website.com/freebies/?section=freebies&page=1`

How can I stop this from happening.

My rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?section=index&page=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^freebies/?$   index.php?section=freebies&page=1  [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/?$    index.php?section=articles&page=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^deals/?$    index.php?section=deals&page=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^freebies/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?section=freebies&page=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?section=articles&page=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^deals/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?section=deals&page=$1  [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`freebies` appear to be a real directory and Apache's `mod_dir` module adds a trailing slash for directories causes a redirect thus exposing your internal URL to clients.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# internally add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?section=index&page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^freebies/?$ index.php?section=freebies&page=1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/?$ index.php?section=articles&page=1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^deals/?$ index.php?section=deals&page=1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^freebies/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?section=freebies&page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?section=articles&page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^deals/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?section=deals&page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thankyou, this was the problem, I have a freebies, deals and articles folder, but didn't realise it would behave this way.

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you need the trailing slash always, so your rules always work.
If that's the case, then above your existing rules, add this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Or if this doesn't work for you, check other techniques for adding trailing slash.

Side tip:
Your existing htacces rules

```
RewriteRule ^freebies/?$   index.php?section=freebies&page=1  [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/?$    index.php?section=articles&page=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^deals/?$    index.php?section=deals&page=1 [L]
```

Can be simplified by just one rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(freebies|articles|deals)/?$   index.php?section=$1&page=1  [L]
```

**EDIT:**
It is possible to do what you ask (work with slash and without slash). I think something like this will do the trick (untested):

```
RewriteRule ^freebies/?$ index.php?section=freebies&page=1
```

(note the ? after the slash)

Also, read https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html) to check how the G treats these scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :)

Is it possible to do this without forcing trailing slashes.

So for example that 'www.website.com/freebies' and 'www.website.com/freebies/' both redirect to 'index.php?section=freebies&page=1'

Comment: RewriteRule ^freebies/?$ index.php?section=freebies&page=1

Is the RewriteRule I am using, but I am having the problem that when I go to: 'www.website.com/freebies', the URL is appearing as 'www.website.com/freebies/?section=freebies&page=1' in the browser.

It only works correctly if I got to 'www.website.com/freebies/' with the trailing slash?

Comment: Anubhava's answer solved the problem, thankyou for the simplified ReWrite Rule though :)